# Closed Question Migrate link

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

Can we/Should we make a link in closed questions that would allow users migrate their questions to a stack exchange networked site that best fits their question as delegated by the closer of said question? I understand that there is a lot that must be done when questions are migrated but I figure that it may aid some sites more than others.

eg. A [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327905/disk-space-and-mounted-network-share) posted in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) instead of [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

<sub>[Inspired by AskUbuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7120/ask-ubuntu-definition#comment11184_7121)</sub>