# Can / should we still migrate already closed questions to another site?

Tags: support, migration

Coming over this (now closed with reasoning *only belongs to a specific site in the network*) question:

- [strange pattern for code validation during creation answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344117/strange-pattern-for-code-validation-during-creation-answer)

I am wondering if we still can suggest to migrate it over to Meta Stack Overflow?

I of course I have found this related post:

- [Closed Question Migrate link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192503/closed-question-migrate-link)

but it's unfortunately unanswered.

So can / should we flag that for moderator attention, and request to migrate it?

What would be the state of the question when migrated? Would it still be closed?

Comment: Hi, if a moderator migrate it it will be open, as to migrate with the moderator tool you need to reopen before, and migrate after. (its a 2 ways step)

Comment: @yagmoth555 Ty. That at least answers the 2nd part of my question.